# How can there be fire inside Mahakal garbhagraha and harm the priests there?

Tags: shiva, temple, shiva-lingam

Is this some leela?
I know the rational answer is some chemical reaction but Mahakal is above all this. If he wants he could have stopped it and the injuries to devotees and priest.
Not to say this will get lot of public attention.
As a devotee I am not able to make sense of this situation. How can people get so injured in sharan of Mahakal. Please explain me.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism, In Hinduism, people suffer due to own karma, not the wrath of any god.